# SSIS - Oracle global temp table not retaining records on next task

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis

I have two oledb tasks. I am inserting records from sql server to an oracle global temp table on one task. Then on the next task I am taking those GTT records, joining them up against another table in oracle, then pulling those results back to the sql server. The insert appears to work per data viewer, but nothing is pulled back in on the second task. I have the retainsamesession property enabled on both servers and I have verified that the records being queried actually pull up data. How can I have the records retained in the GTT on the second task?

Comment: Is this one session per task? You do know that a global temporary table only holds data per session? So if you fill your table in one session, then it's still empty in any other session. This is what Oracle's temporary table's are about after all.

Comment: Two separate tasks. The retain same session property is set to true. My understanding of the property is that it will carry the session over to the next task. However, this is not working.

Comment: If it's the same session, then make sure the table isn't emptied on some commit you may be issuing (this depends on the global temp table type however: is it defined with `PRESERVE ROWS` or `DELETE ROWS`?).

Comment: Sometimes it is better to create a normal table for temporary things. Those global tables are really special and their use is limited.

Comment: Im not doing any kind of commits. It's just a regular oledb task. I'll have to check with our DBA om what type of gtt it is. Unfortunately creating a normal table is not an option.

Comment: Strange. Why can they create a temporary table, but not a normal one? Doesn't seem to make sense. Maybe it's because of some misunderstanding. Temporary tables in Oracle are something very different from temporary tables in SQL Server. They are rarely used. A normal Oracle table is closer to a temporary table in SQL Server then a global temporary one.

Comment: My guess would be to control the amount of storage that's being utilized by analysts. The server belongs to a fortune 500, so naturally theres hundreds of millions of records. They try to keep a tight grip in everything. Maybe I should read up on the differences. I was under the assumption that GTTs qould purge their records at the end of their session. I tested this in an editor and it worked fine. Instead records, joined against another table, then when I closed the editor and re queried the GTT all records were purged.